# Bad <init> method call from inside of a branch

Tags: java, maven, powermock, javassist

After upgrading JDK to **java7u65** several unit-tests utilizing *Mockito* and *PowerMock* started to fail with following causes:

```
15:15:23,807 INFO  - Tests in error: 
15:15:23,810 INFO  -   initializationError(com.your.ClassHere): Bad <init> method call from inside of a branch
```

Answer (score 48, accepted):

**UPDATE**

There are newer java7 versions that fix this issue. As is written in reply to [Powermock / Javassist creates illegal constructors for JDK 1.7.0u65 and 1.8.0u11 with -target 7 #525](https://github.com/jayway/powermock/issues/525)

> upgrading from java 7u71 to 7u75 fixed the problem

**Rootcause**

Upon investigation I heard cries for help from all over the internet from all tools and languages that built upon JDK.

Turns out the cause is new java bytecode standard that gets checked by new verifier. But unfortunately *javassist* sometimes is asked by *powermock* to produce changes into bytecode that are no longer accepted by this new shiny veryfier.

**Workaround (for those who cannot go with newer java)**

As a workaround in [JRebel blog](http://zeroturnaround.com/forums/topic/verifyerror-bad-method-call-from-inside-of-a-branch/) they suggested using **-noverify** flag upon starting JVM
However i found from [Java 7 Bytecode Verifier: Huge backward step for the JVM](http://chrononsystems.com/blog/java-7-design-flaw-leads-to-huge-backward-step-for-the-jvm) blog post alternative workaround that works on java7: **-XX:-UseSplitVerifier**

As my tests run in some unaccessible server and are executed as part of maven build, i needed to find a way to pass that argument along with my project files. First workable solution i discovered is to add this parameter to configurtaion of surefire plugin in pom.xml as follows:

```
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.10</version>
            <configuration>
                <argLine>-XX:-UseSplitVerifier</argLine>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

I suppose that on java8 one could use similar method to call tests with **-noverify** key, but haven't had the chance to confirm that.

**Other related resources to keep eye on**

[Powermock / Javassist creates illegal constructors for JDK 1.7.0u65 and 1.8.0u11 with -target 7.](https://issues.jboss.org/browse/JASSIST-228)
[Powermock / Javassist creates illegal constructors for JDK 1.7.0u65 and 1.8.0u11 with -target 7 #525](https://github.com/jayway/powermock/issues/525)

Comment: A side note, this was never legal, the verifier just missed this check.

Comment: could you pls move the "UPDATE" to the top of the answer? there's no need for the workaround anymore unless there's a blocker to upgrading. thanks.

Comment: Thanks @Creos, I reorderd the answer and put relevant stuff at the top.

Answer (score 7):

Had the same issue with java8 and resolve it by using  -noverify

Comment: Good to hear, in my original answer i suggested it as well. Since i'm using java7, i hadn't verified it yet.

Comment: I had this issue with JDK8v20. Upgrading to JDK8v45 resolved the issue.

Comment: avoid skipping verification, instead pls upgrade to the fixed version of the JDK

Answer (score 5):

I had the same issue as the project was built on jdk1.8.0_51 and I had jdk1.8.0_11 in my machine. 
**The project runs successfully after upgrading to jdk1.8.0_51 in the machine.**